# Footer in wpf DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to show SUM of all columns in a DataGrid as footer. I tried by putting a textblock below the DataGrid. But since I'm using MVVM Model, data cannot be binded since DataGrid and text block are two class references. SO Is it possible in WPF DataGrid? Please help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: well you can not have footer in wpfDataGrid that's true but what stops you from binding I did not understand ? can you post some code and more explanation as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/80a64020-2815-4ce2-9bc0-e3aa0261c365/how-to-add-footer-in-datagrid-wpf) to add footer to your grid..

then you can simply bind to itemssource